# How to get json string of nested typescript interfaces

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have some nested interfaces in typescript, sort of like this:

```
export interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    status: Status;
}

export interface Status {
    location: string;
    activity: number;
}
```

When I get a Person from my server and I want to console.log it, I can do this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(person))
```

This works fine for the top level Person fields, but it just prints "Object" for the status field. I know this is because Status is an interface and does not have a toJSON method. So, I need to get some method to "jsonify" an entire structure of nested interfaces, ie where none of the interfaces have a toJSON method.

How do I do this?

UPDATE: So it turns out everything was indeed working perfectly. The issue is that console.log will only go down to a certain depth (like 2) before it starts printing things like '[Object]' or '[Array]'. To see the full printout I used this instead:

```
console.dir(myobject, {depth: null});
```

Apparently this works just like console.log but does the full printout to arbitrary depth.

Comment: Interfaces don't exist when you run your code. If you're seeing an issue like this, this has to do with the actual code that builds the object, not the interface. I would be curious how you build your Person and Status object.

Comment: @Evert I get the object as a JSON string returned from a server via HTTP GET. I then use a mapping function that maps the variables in the response to a new object using the map() function. So, do I somehow need to add a toJSON method into the created object?

Comment: No you usually do not, but you do need to share more code